# how to use binary search in two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, binary-search, quicksort

I want to compare 2, two dimensional arrays (some specific element)  `arr1[][]`,`arr[][]` in  C++ ,I'm using a for loop to compare them but it took a long time.

Can I use a searching algorithm to implement this like binary search or quick? How can I implement this?

This is my code so far:

```
for (k = 0; k < MAXROW; k++)
{  
  for (m = 0; m <  MAXROW; m++)
   {
     for(j=0;j<MAXCOL;j++)
     {
        if(arr[k][3] ==arr1[m][3]) 
        {
          if((arr[k][1] ==arr1[m][1] && arr[k][2] ==arr1[m][2]))
          {
             cout<<" \n same element";
          }
          else
             cout<<"\n inner  different elements";
        }
        else
           cout<<"\n different elements";
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to tell whether both 2-D arrays are equal (without knowing anything about their organization) is to compare every element. This should have O(mn) running time where m=# of rows and n=# of columns. You appear to have written an extra loop, which may be why you think it's running too slowly. Here's how I would write the comparison:

```
bool are_equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; ++j) {
    if (arr1[i][j] != arr2[i][j]) {
      are_equal = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (are_equal) {
  std::cout << "The arrays are equal." << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "The arrays differ by at least one element." << std::endl;
}
```

To only compare the 3rd and 4th columns (or any subset of columns):

```
int columns_to_check[] = {2, 3}; // Remember that these are 0-indexed
const int NUM_COLS = sizeof(columns_to_check)/sizeof(int);

bool are_equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; ++j) {
    int col = columns_to_check[j];
    if (arr1[i][col] != arr2[i][col]) {
      are_equal = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (are_equal) {
  std::cout << "The arrays are equal." << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "The arrays differ by at least one element." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: but my actual need is i must compare 3 rd 4 th column of each row in the arr1 with arr2 like arr[0][3]==arr1[0][3]..until the last row?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to compare only 3rd and 4th column you can just use one loop .

```
bool are_equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; ++i) {
  if (arr1[i][2] != arr2[i][2]  || arr1[i][3] != arr2[i][3]) {       
     are_equal = false;
     break;
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no you cant use binary search. You have to use 2 loops and compare the arrays element by element. Most of the searching algorithms including binary search uses a key to search in an array. whether the array is 2D or 1D